# How to plot two data sets having different maximum X-axis values in a single plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, I have two data sets showed below. Using position as X, and count as Y, how can I plot them out in different color lines within a single plot using ggplot2 `geom_line`?

dataset `a`:

```
position count
1    3
2    9
3    10
4    15
5    19
6    28
7    15
8    13
9    11
10    5
```

dataset `b`:

```
position count
1    4
2    8
3    16
4    17
5    19
6    10
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to combine your two data frames into a single data frame. First, we create a new identifier column on each data frame:

```
a$dataset = "a"
b$dataset = "b"
```

Then we combine them

```
dd = rbind(a, b)
```

All that's left is to add `geom_line` but condition on the dataset number:

```
ggplot(dd) + geom_line(aes(position, count, colour=dataset))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got this error as before.Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 151, 300
Calls: observed_quality_plot2 ... eval -> eval -> eval -> .Method -> cbind -> data.frame
Execution halted

Comment: @JimMickself: did you really get that error from `rbind`?  It looks like you tried to use `dd = data.frame(a,b)` (which attempts to combine the data frames *columnwise*, and calls `cbind` internally ...